# Using DBDeploy.Net with Rake

Tags: continuous-integration, rake, dbdeploy

We are trying to use DBDeploy.Net for managing our SQL Scripts in a .Net project. We also use a Rake script for automatic builds.
I am unable to find any documentation on how to use DBDeploy.Net with Rake. Is there a nice way of getting DBDeploy working with Rake? (I don't want to create a NAnt script for DBDeploy and call that from Rake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does DbDeploy.net have a command line runner.  If so check out the ExecTask from [Albacore](https://github.com/derickbailey/Albacore/wiki/exec-task).
If you have just started working with DbDeploy.net and are open to options have a look at [FluentMigrator](http://lostechies.com/seanchambers/2011/04/02/fluentmigrator-getting-started/).  It has a command line runner.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for the command line execution of dbdeploy.NET has been added to https://github.com/brunomlopes/dbdeploy.net#command-line.  A lot of new features have been added as well.